# I am trying to connect to the mysql db.The following program gives an error as

Tags: exception, classnotfoundexception

"exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

even i tried to set the .jar file path.then also im getting error

please help

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Connection;

class JdbcExample

{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
            Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","admin");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("exception"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your libraries folder contains the mysql connector for java .jar file which you can download from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.

Your program seems to be okay otherwise.